# Appointment system database modelling

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, erd

I am trying to create an online booking system. I have teachers and students in my system. Teachers specify the date and time they are available for online conversation. Students are able to find available teachers by entering the date, time and duration for interviews.

it is my model =>[database model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XrEb.png)

But there are a problem. For example, if a teacher available 9.00 to 10.00 pm. And, if a student make reservation for 9.30 to 9.45 pm., I should create two available time to 9.00 to 9.30 and 9.45 to 10.00 pm. I think dynamically creating new available times is difficult process. I think a best solution should be. Also, I need some extra time for preparing teacher next conservation. Can u help me about modelling that. I can not find anything about it. There are a lot of room booking system. But not like this. 
Thank you!

Edit: Actually I am asking this question with performance anxiety. Does this process exhaust the server when the data grows? Should I find another solution instead?

Comment: "I think a best solution should be." What do you think it should be?

Comment: Creating 96 * 15-minutes boolean slots per day can better?

Comment: Are 15-minute blocks part of your requirements? Could that change to 10-minute or 20-minute blocks?

Comment: yes it is my requirement. Students can reserve 15,30 and 60 minutes length conservations.

Comment: Why did you tag that UML if you're actually doing ERD?

Comment: @HayreddinTüzel I would record working hours and booked times, and derive available times dynamically by subtracting bookings from working hours.

Comment: @ThomasKilian He's not actually doing ERD either.

Comment: @reaanb thank you for your answering

Comment: @ThomasKilian thank you for editing Thomas. it is my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that proplem with this way:

I created 30 minutes slot. My customers can take 15,30,45 minutes reservations from system. If they take 15 minute-reservation, a slot becomes unavailable. At 30 and 45 minutes reservations, two slot becomes unavailable. I know I gave up 1 hour for a 30-minutes interview. But I could not find another solution. Thank you!

Comment: So why not 15 mins slots, given that 15, 30 and 45 are divisible by 15?

Comment: When I use 15 minute slots, it is difficult to enter data for the appropriate time. For each room, 24 * 4 slots will need to be decided for availability in one day. I chose this method because 15-minutes slots will be cause a bad user experience.

Comment: Tsssssssss.  The [logical] structure of the db should be determined by the nature (/semantics) of the business AND NOTHING ELSE.  Avoiding a "bad user experience" is the responsibility of the software's presentation layer.

Comment: Thank you @ErwinSmout for your help. It is definitely true.